# POST request from web browser throws error while Postman doesn't. How to prevent Axios from putting quotes around values?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, axios, formik

I am using Formik and React to POST to an .NetCore Entity Framework API.

In Postman, it POSTs fine with no errors. However, when doing a POST from a web browser, I am getting an error.

After examining both the Postman request and the request sent by the browser, the only difference I see is this:

Postman works - no quote around the value:

```
"galaxyTypeId": 1,
```

Axios Post - it puts quotes around the value:

```
"galaxyTypeId": "4",
```

I get this error in the browser:

```
POST https://localhost:44376/api/getformdata 400
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
            gameAdminEmail: "",
            adminName: "",
            phone: "",
            galaxyTypeId: 1,
            starId: 1,
            description: "",
            gameUrl: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={async values => {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            axios({
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://localhost:44376/api/getformdata",
                data: values
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}

    >
```

Is there a way to prevent Axios from putting quotes around the number values?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the Controller code and your Statup.cs . Probably an issue relating to the JSON deserialization settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at this codepen here and the issue isn't being reproduced. https://codepen.io/OpenGG/pen/xaGKEP

```
var payload = { "galaxyTypeId": 45 }

axios.post('//httpbin.org/post', payload)
  .then(res => {
    const pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(res.data, null, '  ');
    document.body.appendChild(pre);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    document.body.textContent = err.stack;
  });
```

Do you have a link to the repo?